# Is there any control for auto resize items inside

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

is there any control that can auto resize items inside. I need to contain textblocks inside ItemsControl only in one row, so if total items width larger  then container.Width, it will change each item's width. UWP

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NavigationHistory, ElementName=Main, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          x:Name="BroadComb"
                          MaxHeight="24"
                          Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <HyperlinkButton Command="{Binding Path=NavigateCommand, ElementName=Main}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppAccentForegroundLowBrush}" >
                            <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   TextTrimming="None" 
                                                   Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
                                                   FontSize="10"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   Foreground="{ThemeResource AppAccentForegroundLowBrush}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Path=CanBeTrim}" Value="True">
                                                    <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis"/>
                                                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>

                                                <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Path=CanBeTrim}" Value="False">
                                                    <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
                                                </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <FontIcon Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  FontFamily="ms-appx:/Assets/Fonts/MyBook-Regular.ttf#MyBook"
                                                  FontSize="10"
                                                  Glyph="2" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppAccentForegroundLowBrush}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                        </HyperlinkButton>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a `Grid` with your desired controls in it's columns set to `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="abc" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="xyz" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

This will stretch both controls over the maximum available width according to the Grid's container and make them smaller or bigger if the available space changes.

Most of the time, you will only want to set one column to fill the available space (Width="*") and set the other columns to a fixed or relative width. You can experiment with those settings.

Else we would need a more exact specification of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have binding to itemssource, and need to collapse some textblock.text to trimmed text when total width oversize itemscontrol.

Comment: So you have an ItemsSource that is bound to a list of strings? And the ItemTemplate for this ItemsSouce is a TextBlock? And those should be stacked together in a single line? Could you extend your question with sample code that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. It's clear now how and why you need this. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any control out of the box that can do this in UWP. The caveat is to resize all stacked elements equally, but also relative to their original size. I fear a custom control supporting this would be needed here. Maybe someone else can come up with a solution, but I will think about it and might get back to you later.

Comment: Thank you for post. Will be glad, if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any control that can auto resize items inside. I need to contain textblocks inside ItemsControl only in one row, so if total items width larger then container.Width, it will change each item's width. UWP

What you need is to change the default `ItemsPanel` of GridView. You can create your own Custom Panel to let the texts be arranged in only one row:

1. Create your own custom Panel `OneRowPanel.cs`:

   ```
   public class OneRowPanel:Panel
   {
       double itemHeight=0;
       protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
       {
           int count = Children.Count;
           foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
           {
               child.Measure(new Size(availableSize.Width/count,availableSize.Height));
               if (child.DesiredSize.Height > itemHeight)
               {
                   itemHeight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
               };
           }

           // return the size available to the whole panel
           return new Size(availableSize.Width, itemHeight);
       }

       protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
       {
           // Get the collection of children
           UIElementCollection mychildren = Children;

           // Get total number of children
           int count = mychildren.Count;

           // Arrange children
           int i;
           for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               //get the item Origin Point
               Point cellOrigin = new Point(finalSize.Width / count * i,0);

               // Arrange child
               // Get desired height and width. This will not be larger than 100x100 as set in MeasureOverride.
               double dw = mychildren[i].DesiredSize.Width;
               double dh = mychildren[i].DesiredSize.Height;

               mychildren[i].Arrange(new Rect(cellOrigin.X, cellOrigin.Y, dw, dh));

           }

           // Return final size of the panel
           return new Size(finalSize.Width, itemHeight);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your Xaml and set the `TextBlock.TextTrimming` to `CharacterEllipsis`:

   ```
   <Page
       x:Class="AutoResizeItemsSample.MainPage"
       ...
       mc:Ignorable="d">
       <Page.Resources>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
               </TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Page.Resources>

       <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
           <StackPanel Name="rootPanel">
               <GridView Name="gridView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TextTemplate}" >
                   <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           <local:OneRowPanel ></local:OneRowPanel>
                       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   </GridView.ItemsPanel>
               </GridView>
           </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   </Page>
   ```

Here is the Result:
[image]

Here is the complete demo:[AutoResizeItemsSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/AutoResizeItemsSample).

Comment: I need only one row with textblocks

Comment: Then you will need to create your own custom panel for that. I've implement a simple custom panel for that, please check the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solve this easily with ListView. The ItemsPanel is already a StackPanel and the individual item will resize as needed. If you need the horizontal width of each item to be different, that's supported out of the box, too. I think the solution is to simply choose the ListView control.